# How should I use if-else statement in awk?

Tags: if-statement, awk

I'm writing a parser in bash where I have a text with one ":" in each line, and I need to output the part after a colon if the part before the colon matches the word "txt".

So I divided the text's lines by ":" and then tried to use if-statement in awk.

Command that I've tried:

```
echo "txt:hello" | awk -F: '{if [[ $1="txt" ]] then print $2 fi}'
```

But that resulted in a syntax error in the if-statement, so I wonder if the awk's if-else construction differs from basic bash's?

Comment: Please consult your favorite internet search engine with the words `awk if statement`.

Comment: `echo "txt:hello" | awk -F ':' '{ if($1=="txt") { print $2 } else { print "world" } }'`

Comment: `echo "txt:hello" | awk -F: '$1=="txt"{print $2}' `

Answer (score 2):

> use if-statement in awk.

AWK is not Bash. AWK syntax more resembles C style.

```
awk -F: '{if ($1 == "txt") print $2}'
```

Or just:

```
awk -F: '$1 == "txt"{print $2}'
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Very-Simple .